# Отметка вопросов "пустышек", личный черный список

Tags: обсуждение

Как поступать с вопросами на которые ответ невозможен и никакой пользы они не представляют?

> Пример: Что не так с кодом
>
> Ответы: Все верно
>
> Автор: Само заработало.

При этом они висят в неотвеченных и мешают ответить на другие.

**Основной вопрос: как их занести в черный список**

Дополнительный: какие действия принимать для привлечения внимания.

Comment: Да, таких вопросов полно. Скажем, топикстартер приводит ссылку на длинную статью по настройке <чего-нибудь>, у него "не работает". И статья хорошая, и всё правильно... Причём раз на раз не приходится: кому-то найдётся сердобольный отвечающий (ради репы чего только не сделают), кому-то нет.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Первая же причина закрытия в разделе *"Не по теме"* подходит:

[image: закрывашка]

> Вопрос вызван **проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится, или опечаткой**

Если не можете это сделать сами (репутация не позволяет), оставьте соответствующую **тревогу**, придут вооружённые закрывашками участники. Возможно, не сразу. В тяжёлых случаях [можно вызвать группу *медленного* реагирования в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--).

Заброшенные закрытые вопросы без полезных ответов в конечном счёте удаляются.

Comment: Тревогу выбираем "требуется вмешательство модератора Другая проблема, требующая реакции модератора. Опишите её подробно и конкретно! " И какую причину пишем?

Comment: @Igor нет, тревогу выбираем "должен быть закрыт", "не по теме" и причина выше.

Comment: Не по теме у меня всего лишь два варианта 1) Скорее всего, данный вопрос не относится ни к обсуждению работы сайта Stack Overflow на русском, ни к программному обеспечению сети Stack Exchange, согласно правилам, описанным в справке.
2) Другое (добавьте комментарий, объясняющий причину закрытия)

Comment: @Igor первое. Вопрос попадёт в очередь к закрывашкам.

Comment: @Igor Это причины закрытия на мете. Попробуйте на основном сайте.